# Attach Native Client Module into google chrome at run-time

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hook, google-nativeclient

I have a tool to set up a hook. It is built by C++, and hook code is actually running in the browser process. For IE, it is very easy to obtain the document and then get the entire DOM via API/Interface exposed by *mshtml.dll*.

Now, I have to make this tool work for Google Chrome as it can do for IE. I have couple question:

1. Does Google Chrome expose any interface that I can obtain from C++.
2. Since I am not able to find out a good source to answer #1 question, I think about building a NaCl module. This module will interact with my C++ module and it will interact with Google Chrome to get the DOM. The challenge here is how to attach NaCl module into every Google Chrome process. I am asking the method which is similar to `LoadLibrary` API used in loading a DLL. Because I have had the native code running in the every Google Chrome process.
3. If #2 is not feasible, is building an extension for Google Chrome doable?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you will want to create chrome extension.  Using an extension you can interact directly with DOM using JavaScript.  You can also build your C++ code as a NaCl module which can be part of your extension.  The only way for the JavaScript and C++ code to communicate is via the PostMessage interface.  Direct access to the DOM from C++ is not possible.